# iphone - have a button load a new page

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to learn iphone app. development. Can someone direct me to a tutorial that explains how to add a button which loads a webpage.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=463648

p.s. you won't get far if you can not find a simple information like that using google.
Most likely you'll have a lot of questions - try to look into Apple sample applications.